# How to get json column value in postgresql with querydsl?

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, querydsl

Our prjoect configurations are

- Spring Boot :: (v2.6.0)
- Java 11.0.15
- Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
- com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-55:2.20.0

I'd like get json column value.

The json column is here:

[image]

[image]

How can I get "isOption1" property in json column?

The query is here:

[image]

By the way, running the query caused an "QuerySyntaxException".

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: with near line 2, column 63 [select tranOrdTest.uid, tranOrdTest.tranOrdKey, tranOrdTest.tranCarOption, tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 as isOption1
> from tranOrdTest.tranCarOption as tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 with key(tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0) = ?1, kr.co.conc.deliveryserver.biz.tr.tranOrd.entity.TranOrdTest tranOrdTest]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: with near line 2, column 63 [select tranOrdTest.uid, tranOrdTest.tranOrdKey, tranOrdTest.tranCarOption, tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 as isOption1
> from tranOrdTest.tranCarOption as tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 with key(tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0) = ?1, kr.co.conc.deliveryserver.biz.tr.tranOrd.entity.TranOrdTest tranOrdTest]
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: with near line 2, column 63 [select tranOrdTest.uid, tranOrdTest.tranOrdKey, tranOrdTest.tranCarOption, tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 as isOption1
> from tranOrdTest.tranCarOption as tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 with key(tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0) = ?1, kr.co.conc.deliveryserver.biz.tr.tranOrd.entity.TranOrdTest tranOrdTest]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: with near line 2, column 63 [select tranOrdTest.uid, tranOrdTest.tranOrdKey, tranOrdTest.tranCarOption, tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 as isOption1
> from tranOrdTest.tranCarOption as tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0 with key(tranOrdTest_tranCarOption_0) = ?1, kr.co.conc.deliveryserver.biz.tr.tranOrd.entity.TranOrdTest tranOrdTest]

SO how can I resolve this issue?

Please comment if you have the solution for this issue.

Thanks.

I don't want to use native query; I want to use querydsl method.

Query is working except getting json value

[image]

but query is not working include the json value.

I want to get "isOption1" property.

Please let me know how can I do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate 6.2 for this purpose, which allows you to map an `@Embeddable` to a JSON column like this:

```java
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
@Column(name = "trancaroptions")
TranCarOptions options;

record TranCarOptions(String isOption1 ,String isOption2, String isOption3, String isOption4, String isOption5) {}
```